# IllegalStateException при отматывании Fragment назад

Tags: android, android-fragment, fragment-transaction, fragment-manager

`fragment1` и `fragment2` - простейшие фрагменты с цветным фоном и одной надписью. Вот один из них, второй точно такой же:

```
package ru.xpendence.development.fragmentmanagerlearning;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by promoscow on 16.05.17.
 */

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, null);
    }
}
```

Они обрабатываются при помощи `FragmentManager` и `FragmentTransaction`:

```
package ru.xpendence.development.fragmentmanagerlearning;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Fragment1 fragment1;
    Fragment2 fragment2;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragment1 = new Fragment1();
        fragment2 = new Fragment2();
        Log.d("onCreate", "okay");
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Log.d("onClick", String.valueOf(fragmentTransaction));

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonAdd :
                Log.d("onClick", "buttonAdd");
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fromCont, fragment1);
                break;
            case R.id.buttonRemove :
                Log.d("onClick", "buttonRemove");
                fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment1);
                break;
            case R.id.buttonReplace :
                Log.d("onClick", "buttonReplace");
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fromCont, fragment2);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("1");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        Log.d("onClick", "commited");
    }
}
```

После хаотичных тыканий по кнопкам я начинаю отматывать назад активности при помощи кнопки "Назад", при этом иногда приложение схлопывается и вылетает следующее:

```
05-16 19:31:06.683 13651-13651/? E/InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal.
05-16 19:31:06.683 13651-13651/? E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
05-16 19:31:06.684 13651-13651/? E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: Fragment1{2cb49a7f #0 id=0x7f0b0062}
                                                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1138)
                                                         at android.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:1547)
                                                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1504)
                                                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:499)
                                                         at android.app.Activity.onBackPressed(Activity.java:2479)
                                                         at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2453)
                                                         at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2633)
                                                         at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2704)
                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2221)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3918)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3611)
                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3772)
                                                         at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2208)
                                                         at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1849)
                                                         at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1840)
                                                         at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2185)
                                                         at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
                                                         at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                         at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
05-16 19:31:06.685 13651-13651/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-16 19:31:06.686 13651-13651/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: ru.xpendence.development.fragmentmanagerlearning, PID: 13651
                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: Fragment1{2cb49a7f #0 id=0x7f0b0062}
                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1138)
                                                       at android.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:1547)
                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1504)
                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:499)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.onBackPressed(Activity.java:2479)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2453)
                                                       at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2633)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2704)
                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2221)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3918)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3611)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3772)
                                                       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2208)
                                                       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1849)
                                                       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1840)
                                                       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2185)
                                                       at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
                                                       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Схлопывается не всегда, но хочется понять причину и решить её в зародыше. Надеюсь на помощь.

Comment: `Fragment already added`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя replace, ты сохраняет фрагменты в стэк. Удаляя фрагмент, ты не оповещаешь свой стэк об этом. Должно помочь:

```
 case R.id.buttonRemove :
                Log.d("onClick", "buttonRemove");
                fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment1);
                fragmentManager.popBackStack();
                break;
```